# I receive a Error says , ‘Unable to find JDBC driver.’ error when using the Database Toolbox 3.9 (R2015a) to connect to an SQL Server database?

Tags: java, sql-server, matlab, jdbc

I have created a database connection in MS SQL Server Management Studio. And i am trying to connect MS SQL with MATLAB. Given below the code which i tried to connect it. And i receive an error says Unable to find JDBC driver.

```
      function [Out, Settings] = MSSQLconn(dbname, userpassmethod, varargin)

% MSSQLCONN Establishes connection with MS SQL 
% 
%   MSSQLCONN(DBNAME) Every other input by default
%       - dbname: database name to which you want to connect (char format)
%       
%   MSSQLCONN(DBNAME, USERPASSMETHOD) Supply username and password, else by default
%       - userpassmethod --> {'username','password'}; 1st cell username,2nd cell password
%       - userpassmethod --> '-win'; use windows authentication (only for R2008b)
%       - userpassmethod --> '-manual'; supply credentials through inputdlg
%
%   MSSQLCONN(DBNAME,USERPASSMETHOD,OPTIONAL1...3) Supply variable number of optionals. 
%       - servername: string with the server where the database is hosted
%       - portnumber: integer of the port
%       - oldversion: if MS SQL is older than 2005 ed. supply '-old';
%
%   [OUT,SETTINGS] = ...
%       - Class 'database': connection to the server.
%       - Class 'structure' with the settings used to connect (except password).
%
%   DEFAULT SETTINGS:
%       - user = ''; 
%       - pass = '';
%       - server = 'localhost';
%       - port = 1433;
%       - driver = 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver' (MS SQL 2005 and above);
%       - windows authentication: false;
%
% Examples:
%   - MSSQLconn('MyDB')                      % use the whole set of default settings
%   - MSSQLconn('MyDB',{'Oleg','****'})      % supply username and password 
%   - MSSQLconn('MyDB',{'Oleg',''})          % supply just the username, password by inputdlg 
%   - MSSQLconn('MyDB','-win')               % use windows authentication 
%   - MSSQLconn('MyDB','-manual')            % supply both username and password through inputdlg
%   - MSSQLconn(...,'myserver')              % supply servername with any combination of dbname and userpassmethod 
%   - MSSQLconn(...,1433, 'myserver','-old') % full set of optionals
%
% Additional features: 
% - <a href="matlab: web('http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937724.aspx','-browser')">MS SQL server JDBC Driver Webpage</a>
% - <a href="matlab: web('http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25577-ms-sql-jdbc-connection','-browser')">FEX MSSQLconn page</a>
% - <a href="matlab: web('http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-9SHNAT/','-browser')">TMW Support Win Authentication</a>
% 
% See also DATABASE

% Author: Oleg Komarov (oleg.komarov@hotmail.it)
% Date: 13 oct 2009 - created
%       14 oct 2009 - added links to MS JDBC drivers and to FEX submission page
%       28 oct 2009 - reorganized input checks and added single input syntax
%       11 nov 2009 - changed input syntax; added win authentication, TMW support link and settings output


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% CHECK part 
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% 1. # of inputs
error(nargchk(1,5,nargin))

% 2. dbname
if ~ischar(dbname);  error('MSSQLconn:strFmt', 'dbname must be char'); end

% 3. userpassmethod
if nargin == 1 || isempty(userpassmethod); 
    method = '-default';
elseif iscell(userpassmethod)
    method = '-cell';
else method = userpassmethod;
end
winAuth = 'false'; user = ''; pass = '';                                      % Default values
switch method
    case '-default'                                                           % Use default values
    case '-cell'
        if numel(userpassmethod) == 2                                         % [1] IF 2 cells
        user = userpassmethod{1}; pass = userpassmethod{2};
            if ~isempty(user) && ischar(user) && isempty(pass)                % [2] IF pass empty
            while isempty(pass) 
                pass = inputdlg('Supply password: ', 'Empty not admitted',1); 
                pass = pass{:};
            end
            elseif ~isempty(pass) && ischar(pass) && isempty(user)            % [2] IF user empty
            while isempty(user) 
                user = inputdlg('Supply username: ', 'Empty not admitted',1); 
                user = user{:};
            end
            end
        else error('MSSQLconn:upmFmt', 'userpassmethod wrong format');               
        end
    case '-win'
        if any(str2double(struct2cell(ver('database'))) < 3.5) ;
           error('MSSQLconn:wauMth', 'Feature unavailable for Database Toolbox release older than 3.5 (R2008b)')
        else winAuth = 'true';
        end
    case '-manual'
         while isempty(user) || isempty(pass)
            userpass = inputdlg({'Supply username: '; 'Supply password: '}, 'ENTER BOTH',1,{'',''},'on');
            user = userpass{1}; pass = userpass{2};
        end
end

% 4. Oldver
IDXo = strcmp('-old',varargin);
if any(IDXo)
    drv = 'com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver'; 
else
    drv = 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver'; 
end

% 5. Port
IDXn = cellfun(@isnumeric,varargin);
if nnz(IDXn) == 1 && mod(varargin{IDXn},1) == 0
    port = num2str(varargin{IDXn});
elseif nnz(IDXn) > 1 
    error('MSSQLconn:prtFmt', 'Only one numeric integer port is accepted')
else port = '1433';
end

% 6. Server
IDXs = cellfun(@ischar, varargin) & ~IDXo;
if any(IDXs); server = varargin{IDXs}; else server = 'localhost'; end

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% ENGINE part
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Url concatenation
URL = ['jdbc:sqlserver://' server ':' port ';database=' dbname ';integratedSecurity=' winAuth ';']; 

% Set connection timeout (s)
logintimeout(drv, 10);

% Connect
Out = database('', user, pass, drv, URL);

% Settings 
if nargout == 2 
    Settings = cell2struct({dbname; user; drv; server; port; ~strcmp(winAuth,';');Out.Message},...
    {'login'; 'thusha-PC\thusha'; 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver'; 'localhost'; '53811'; 'windowsAuthentication'; 'errorMsg'});
end

% [1] IF connected
if isconnection(Out)
    % Initialize Status
    Status = '.';
    % [2] IF readonly
    if isreadonly(Out); Status = ' in "READONLY" mode.'; end % [2]
    % Display connection status
    sprintf('Connected%s', Status)
else % [1] IF not connected
    % Display error
    error('MSSQLconn:conInv',Out.Message)
end % [1]

end
```

Comment: It would be great if you could be particular about the problem. Where exactly is your issue? You may also have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to improve the question. Welcome to SO!

Comment: i followed the below Guide to create a connection between MSSQL and MATLAB, i have completed the steps up to 5 and as shown in this link i received the Error message called JDBC Driver file was not found on MATLAB Java Class.  After as it mentioned i followed the Step-04, but still it's not working. Please guide me!!   http://in.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/microsoft-sql-server-jdbc-windows.html?s_tid=answers_rc2#bt8kmbi-1

Comment: Which version of the JDBC driver did you install in step 4? Maybe you installed a very old version, or - for example - you installed a Java 8 (JDBC 4.2) version, but Matlab is running on Java 7 (note: just a theory, I don't know anything about Matlab).

Comment: I have installed the Java 8 version and Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.0 version for SQL Server. MATLAB Version is (R2015a). Could you please let me know the compatible version of Java in order to Run this system.